# Using Rx and Tx pins(0 and 1) on Arduino Uno for GSM

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, gsm, sketch

I am using a GSM module sim800. My module responds to the output given by my PIR sensor and sends sms according to it. My module has got +5V, GND, Rx and Tx pins. What are the pin connections that I have to make?

Comment: my INFINIX x510 isn't reconginz the USB cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My module has got +5V, GND, Rx and Tx pins. What are the pin connections that I have to make?

TX => RX, RX => TX, that is Arduino TX to module RX, and TX to module RX. If you want to use [Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) the pins are 0 for Arduino RX, and 1 for Arduino TX.

If you want to use [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialConstructor) you decide which pins to use (check the documentation for valid pins on your board).

```
// Use software serial with pin 2 for rx and pin 3 for tx
SoftwareSerial gsm(2,3);
```

Cheers!

Comment: when I use software serial an error pops up during uploading: 'SoftwareSerial' does not name a type.

Comment: #include <SoftwareSerial.h>, https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample

Comment: the rx pin from module to 2 pin of microcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice.

Always:

- GND => GND
- +5V => +5V

Then, either:

- TX => RX (0)
- RX => TX (1)

and use the hardware UART "Serial", but that then means that uploading new code to your Arduino becomes an arduous task since the usage pins 0 and 1 will interfere with that.  So the other option:

- TX => Any pin
- RX => Any pin

And then use [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) to set up a secondary "bit banged" serial port on the two pins you choose.